# Join two xml files using XPath query in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm new to C# and I have two xml files which are loaded into my program as XDocument. I wanna find a way to perform an inner join and store the result as a new file. I'm not sure how I can achieve this by using XPath queries.

Say here is my first xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<People>
  <Person>
    <ID> 1 </ID>
    <Gender> M </Gender>
  </Person>

  <Person>
    <ID> 2 </ID>
    <Gender> F </Gender>
  </Person>
</People>
```

And here's my second xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PeopleDetail>
  <PersonDetail>
    <ID> 1 </ID>
    <Name> ABC </Name>
  </PersonDetail>

  <PersonDetail>
    <ID> 2 </ID>
    <Name> DEF </Name>
  </PersonDetail>
</PeopleDetail>
```

And what I wanna get it something like this:

```
<Output>
  <Join>
    <Person>
      <ID> 1 </ID>
      <Gender> M </Gender>
    </Person>
    <PersonDetail>
      <ID> 1 </ID>
      <Name> ABC </Name>
    </PersonDetail>
  </Join> 

  <Join>
    <Person>
      <ID> 2 </ID>
      <Gender> F </Gender>
    </Person>
    <PersonDetail>
      <ID> 2 </ID>
      <Name> DEF </Name>
    </PersonDetail>
  </Join> 
</Output>
```

Both files are loaded into my program by using the XDocument.Load() method:

```
var doc1 = XDocument.Load("first.xml");
var doc2 = XDocument.Load("second.xml");
```

So can anyone tell me how to perform such inner join by "ID" ?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to describe what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure XPath will be of much use to you here, but you can do a simple join using LINQ and create a new document containing these elements.  For clarity, I've renamed `doc1` and `doc2` to `people` and `details`:

```
var joins = from person in people.Descendants("Person")
            join detail in details.Descendants("PersonDetail")
                on (int)person.Element("ID") equals (int)detail.Element("ID")
            select new XElement("Join", person, detail);

var output = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Output",
        joins
        )
    );
```

You can see  a working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HP5VtD

Comment: Thanks~ sorry about the confusion, it has nothing to do with XPath in the example above. But I did use XPathSelectElements() in my actual program to pick up desired data only.
So what I finally did is something like this and it works perfectly: 
from person in doc1.XPathSelectElements("query goes here")